# String Match between i and j in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

How to define the value of i and j in one or two sentences.If i and j match, it should return true. The value of i and j can be a "Noun phrase", or "Pronoun. example:

```
list= [('اکلیل', 'N'), ('احمد', 'Ne'), ('استاد', 'N'), ('پوهنتون', 'Ne'), ('کابل', 
    'N'), ('است', 'V'), ('.', 'PUNC'), ('او', 'PRO'), ('هر', 'DET'), ('روز', 'N'), 
    ('ساعت', 'Ne'), ('۸', 'NUM'), ('بجه', 'N'), ('به', 'P'), ('کار', 'N'), 
    ('میرود', 'V'), ('.', 'PUNC')]

    for i, j in list: 
        if i == 'NP'and j =='PRO':
           ......
```

Comment: Why the **uncommented** down-votes of this **new visitor**? OP: Make sure you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need **both** values to be present on the same `set` for the result to be `True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've understood your problem this might be the nearest answer to your problem

```
list= [('اکلیل', 'N'), ('احمد', 'Ne'), ('استاد', 'N'), ('پوهنتون', 'Ne'), ('کابل', 'N'), ('است', 'V'), ('.', 'PUNC'), ('او', 'PRO'), ('هر', 'DET'), ('روز', 'N'), ('ساعت', 'Ne'), ('۸', 'NUM'), ('بجه', 'N'), ('به', 'P'), ('کار', 'N'), ('میرود', 'V'), ('.', 'PUNC')]

for i,j in list:
    if ( j == 'N' or j == 'PRO'):
        return True
        #your code goes here
```